# Scaling image before loading on to canvas

Tags: android, file-upload, paint, image-scaling

So, this is my code for loading an image from the SD Card on to the canvas in order to be able to draw on it. However in most cases the image appears stretched and distorted. I would like the code, to scale the image so that it looks proportionate on the canvas. Please help me. Thank you.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
if (requestCode == 1) {
Uri currImageURI = data.getData();
String s= getRealPathFromURI(currImageURI);
File file = new File(s);

if (file.exists()) {
Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(file.getAbsolutePath());
drawView.setBackground(d);
}
else
{
   // Toast the user
}

}
}
}
```

Comment: That's not the way to draw an image in the canvas. Use canvas.drawBitmap method. developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html

Answer (score 0):

You are not using a `Canvas`, I belive that you are using an `ImageView` to show your image.

instead of using `setBackground()`, use `setImageDrawable()`

If you are still getting distorion in your image, use `setScaleType()` and use one of the `scaleTypes` listed here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html